# How do I remove an unsuccessful installion of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, storage

Before a few days, I tried to install Ubuntu on Windows10 machine.
I downloaded the Ubuntu software and mounted it on a flash drive, etc.....
In the middle of the installation(partition part),
The installation froze and didn’t progress.
I stopped the installation, turned off my laptop, and took out the flash drive.
After a day, I (for some reason) checked my storage space, it was 30GB from being full, after being 150GB far from being full.
Any solutions?

Comment: Format the partition, where you tried to install the Ubuntu.

Comment: You didn't mention what release of Ubuntu (did you verify your download? and write to your install media? as that's what I'd check first on a 'freeze'), however you don't need to do anything to remove Ubuntu - just use the space it was using with something else. If you had `grub` installed (it sounds like you didn't get that far) or UEFI setup, you may also want to delete that (or make windows own the MBR so `grub` isn't used) but you were vague with details, so we don't know if any of this applies to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to install Ubuntu, directly mount your bootable USB/CD/etc and you can repeat the installation process again like you did before. While installing the OS, wipe the drive that you have previously tried installing Ubuntu and install the OS on that drive.

If you want to completely remove that drive and add it back to your windows, follow [this link](https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/).

Hope it helps you!